# Filter an array and create a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a very simple requirement for filter some objects from a larger array and create a sub-array. Right now, I'm doing it as follows, but I'm wondering whether I could do inline and avoid the for-each.

```
        var branches = $filter('filter')(vm.locations, { 'fkLocationTypeId': 5 });
        vm.branchList = [];
        angular.forEach(branches, function (obj) {
            vm.branchList.push({ id: obj.Id,  label: obj.locationDisplayName });
        });
```

Comment: you do realise there's an in-built `filter` function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: yes, the reason I'm creating a separate array is I only want an id-value pair in the second array.

Comment: then combine filter and map. And you need to provide more code, because from what you've given, it's too difficult to help

Comment: What is your filter criteria? What will be the input and expected output?

Comment: from the locations array, I need to filter out the locations with type=5, and then create a new array with only the Id and the displayname. the new array is branchList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to both filter the array and modify the retained items, you can use `filter()` in combination with `map()`, both native array methods

```
vm.branchList = vm.locations
  .filter(function(location) {
    return location.fkLocationTypeId === 5;
  })
  .map(function(location) {
    return {
      id: location.Id,
      label: location.locationDisplayName
    };
  });
```

If you want to avoid iterating over the array twice you can use the `reduce()` method to perform both the filtering and mapping at the same time

```
vm.branchList = vm.locations
  .reduce(function(builtList, location) {
    if (location.fkLocationTypeId === 5) {
      return builtList.concat({
        id: location.Id,
        label: location.locationDisplayName
      });
    }
    return builtList;
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's much wrong with your use of `forEach`, but you could replace it by a `map` operation on the filtered set.

Personally, I'd use `reduce` to combine both `filter` and `map` operations in one loop, but you'd probably only start seeing a performance increase when you're filtering very large sets of data.

To combine the two in one reducer:

```js
const locToObj = loc => 
  ({ id: loc.Id,  label: loc.locationDisplayName });
 
const branchReducer = (acc, loc) =>
  loc.fkLocationTypeId === 5
    ? (acc.push(locToObj(loc)), acc)
    : acc
 
const branches = vm.locations.reduce(branchReducer, []);
```